# Silverdiagram sdk

Tags: .net, silverlight, codeplex

I'm trying to run some examples from silverdiagram.codeplex.com but there are some missing libraries. After searching a lot in google i found that there is a SDK that i should download to make it compile. 
The main problem here is that silverdiagram web site is down, so i cannot get the missing libraries.
Is there any other place where i could get it?

This is an example of my compiling errors
Error   11  The name "Diagram" does not exist in the namespace "http://schemas.silverdiagram.net/sd/2010/xaml". C:\example\src\SD.Samples\SD.Shapes.Samples.DragDrop\MainPage.xaml  54  21  SD.Shapes.Samples.DragDrop